# Ical events don't show as cards in an recipients email box

Tags: javascript, node.js, icalendar, sendgrid

I'm trying to send out calendar events to users using the iCalender standard. I want their inbox to automatically detect the event and display it to the user like the image below.

[image]

My isc data is

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:adamgibbons/ics
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:a8b44b40-30fc-11e8-9cdf-ab421c95fe5f
SUMMARY:Test Event
DTSTAMP:20180326T125000Z
DTSTART:20180529
DTEND:20180530
DESCRIPTION:This is a test event
LOCATION:Somewhere in a building...
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN=Admin:mailto:test@test.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CN=test@test.com:mailto:test@test.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I'm using the node package 'ics' to make the ics data and the following code to send the email.

```
var encodedEvent = Base64.encode(event)
    var msg = {
        to: to,
        from: from,
        subject: 'Registration an Event',
        text: 'Thanks for registering for an event.',
        html: '<strong>Thanks for registering for an event.</strong>',
        attachments: [{
            content: encodedEvent,
            filename: 'invite.ics',
            type: 'text/calendar',
            disposition: 'attachment',
            contentId: 'mytext'
        }],
        headers: {
            method: "REQUEST"
        }
    }
    sgMail.setApiKey(apiKey)
    sgMail.send(msg)
        .then( (data) => { console.log("data", data) })
        .catch( (err) => { console.log("Error:", err) })
```

Now SendGrid is sending the email and the email has the attachment "invite.ics" but inboxes don't seem to detect it. From my research it might be a problem with headers but i'm not sure, i've tried a few things so far and nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood - are you attempting to control what the recipients unknown email program does with a ics attachment?  Not possible.  Best you can do is provide as correct an ics file as you can.  Google ics validator or icalendar validators.   They vary in what they check and how accurate they are, but will help.

Comment: @anmari Ummm, so kind of.... I want to send calendar events using the icalendar standard. This should, in most cases show a card or information at the top of the email allowing a user to easily action the even in their calendar. like the above picture. Now i'm not bother if they don't have that feature available or switched off, i'm not trying to force it but in my mail box it should detect the ical attachment but it doesn't.